# using instance attribute from another class. Python

Tags: python, class, parent

I need to get to instance attribute of a class from another one. Im thinking about it, and it looks like it should work, but it doesn't. Can You give me some help?

I need to get to swidget and searchWidget witch are in MainWindow, from MainWidget

```
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):

        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()

        self.mainWidget = MainWidget(self)
        self.searchWidget = SearchWidget(self)
        self.swidget = QStackedWidget()
        self.swidget.addWidget(self.mainWidget)
        self.swidget.addWidget(self.searchWidget)    
        self.setCentralWidget(self.swidget)           
        self.initUI()

        ...
```

and the MainWidget class:

```
class MainWidget(QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent):

        super(MainWidget,self).__init__(parent)
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):

        ...

    def goSearch(self):
        self.parent.swidget.setCurrentWidget(self.parent.searchWidget)
```

Ive got the problem in the last line (def doSearch())
The interpreter says:

```
File "/home/maze/Develop/StartApp/startapp.py", line 71, in goSearch
    self.parent.swidget.setCurrentWidget(self.parent.searchWidget)
AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'swidget'
```

What Im doing wrong here? Thanks for Your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need this in your constructor for `class MainWidget`:

```
self.parent = parent
```

The variable sent to the constructor is "out of scope" everywhere else in your class.

Comment: God bless You, phantom

Comment: Bless You and stackoverflow.com!